# CALL_NON_FUNCTION_AS_CONSTRUCTOR (native) NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

This code works in other situations but I think the setup of the file is what is causing the issue and I'm not sure how to get around it. It's a contract job so I don't have the ability to change the setup of the fil and I'm not sure how to fix this error.

I'm calling the OAuth module from here:

```
var common = require('common');
var OAuth2 = require('oauth2');
var google = require('google');

exports.init = function(app) {

app.get('/oauth/google', function(req, res) {
    var gmailAuthObject =
        new OAuth2(google.clientId,
                   google.clientSecret,
                   '',
                   'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
                   'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token');
    var redirectUrl = gmailAuthObject.getAuthorizeUrl(
        { redirect_uri:google.callbackRedirect,
          scope:'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds',
          response_type:'code',
          access_type:'offline' });

    res.redirect(redirectUrl);
});

app.get('/oauth/google/callback',  function(req, res) {
    var code = req.query.code;
    var content = '<script>' +
        'window.opener.SITENAME.setGoogleCode("' + code + '");' +
        'window.close();' +
        '</script>';
    res.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    res.end(content, 'utf-8');
});

// Other Networks...
/******************************************************************************/

};
```

It's failing at new OAuth2 with: CALL_NON_FUNCTION_AS_CONSTRUCTOR (native)

The OAuth module as exports on each function like `exports.OAuth2`.

I'm guessing the issue is because it's inside `exports.init` but I can't fix it. Any ideas or help here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using [this module](https://github.com/lexer/node-oauth2/), it seems that you should do (on the second line of your supplied code):

```
var OAuth2 = require("oauth2").OAuth2;
```

Comment: Haha, yep that's it. I had just figured it out and was answering my own question. Having a stupid day apparently. Thanks for your help.